# LuisIntent Attribute not being correctly recognised

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I am working through a course [Getting Started with Building Bots on the Microsoft Bot Framework](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/microsoft-bot-framework-getting-started-update/table-of-contents) and using some code from the course.

When I type "Hi" in the bot emulator, Luis realises that it is a Greeting Intent however the Bot catches it as a None Intent and says " I'm sorry I don't know what you mean"

```
[Serializable]
public class LUISDialog : LuisDialog<BugReport>
{
 private readonly BuildFormDelegate<BugReport> NewBugReport;

 public LUISDialog(BuildFormDelegate<BugReport> newBugReport)
 {
    this.NewBugReport = newBugReport;
 }

[LuisIntent("Greeting")]
public async Task Greeting(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    context.Call(new GreetingDialog(), Callback);
}
[LuisIntent("")]
public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    await context.PostAsync("I'm sorry I don't know what you mean."); 
    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
}
```

I have not set up any utterances for the None intent.

Below shows that the result is a Greeting Intent in the debugger:

[image: in the debugger]

The exported .json is as follows

```
    {
  "luis_schema_version": "3.0.0",
  "versionId": "0.1",
  "name": "sbdbotapp",
  "desc": "",
  "culture": "en-us",
  "intents": [
    {
      "name": "GreetingIntent"
    },
    {
      "name": "NewBugReportIntent"
    },
    {
      "name": "None"
    },
    {
      "name": "QueryBugType"
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "BugType",
      "roles": []
    }
  ],
  "composites": [],
  "closedLists": [],
  "patternAnyEntities": [],
  "regex_entities": [],
  "prebuiltEntities": [
    {
      "name": "email",
      "roles": []
    }
  ],
  "model_features": [],
  "regex_features": [],
  "patterns": [],
  "utterances": [
    {
      "text": "bug report",
      "intent": "NewBugReportIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "can you check whether foo is a bugtype?",
      "intent": "QueryBugType",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "BugType",
          "startPos": 22,
          "endPos": 24
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "create bug",
      "intent": "NewBugReportIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "good afternoon",
      "intent": "GreetingIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "good evening",
      "intent": "GreetingIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "good morning",
      "intent": "GreetingIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "hello",
      "intent": "GreetingIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "hey",
      "intent": "GreetingIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "hi",
      "intent": "GreetingIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "hi there",
      "intent": "GreetingIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "i have a problem",
      "intent": "NewBugReportIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "is security a bug type?",
      "intent": "QueryBugType",
      "entities": [
        {
          "entity": "BugType",
          "startPos": 3,
          "endPos": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "something doesnt work",
      "intent": "NewBugReportIntent",
      "entities": []
    },
    {
      "text": "yo",
      "intent": "GreetingIntent",
      "entities": []
    }
  ]
}
```

[Update]

From DFBerry's help and re-looking at the course, I see the course is using the SDK, where as the Doc's tutorial uses a Web App Bot.

Comment: Please add a link to the course and the JSON from the exported LUIS app.

Comment: @DFBerry Thanks for your interest, I have done that now.

Comment: 1) each intent needs utterances. 2) The BF code needs all intents. 3) Please use the LUIS/BF tutorial with your app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-csharp-tutorial-build-bot-framework-sample. If you can get your app working with Azure Bot Service, in the tutorial, then you can get the class bot to work.

Comment: Interesting, my old bot in Azure shows as a Cogintive Service. My new one as per your link shows as a Bot Service.... waiting my 10 mins now.

Comment: Ah, when I go to https://au.luis.ai  I can see the new app already there. No need to add it.

Comment: I added the Cancel and Help intents to my code (Greeting and None were already there ) but when I run in the Bot Emulator I get "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue" Response code 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: All of the intents in LUIS must be in the bot. All the intents in the bot should be in LUIS. Run the bot code locally - download via zip file then use bot emulator.

Comment: Thank you, I have the download file working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because the name of your intent is "greetingIntent" and in your code you have it labeled as just "greeting".  Change your code to be "greetingIntent" and it should work.